# Unable to write to an .xls file (MatLab)

Tags: matlab, spreadsheet, xls

I wanted to edit a certain .xls spreadsheet in MatLab by, say, inserting number 3 into cell H4. I typed out following code:

```
xlswrite('list.xls', 3, 1, 'H4')
```

but it doesn't change anything. The spreadsheet is left seemingly untouched but xlswrite returns 1 as the write succeeded output...
Any ideas on what might be going on?
Cheers.

Comment: Just look on description of this function. That say xlswrite(filename,A,sheet) or xlswite(filename,A,xlrange). So, what is your array and what is your sheet or xlrange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
xlswrite('test',3,'H4:H4')
```